# React - refetch child component data when the props change

Tags: reactjs, render, state

I have a Parent component with state 'form_type'.  That parent has a child like

```
<Child 
    url='myroot.com?formtype=' + this.state.form_type 
/>
```

When I change the `form_type` state, I need the child to `reload`, getting the new url endpoint.

Any thoughts?  I can see that the parent is rendering when the state changes.

Comment: This is the expected behavior of React. Can you post the full code?

Answer (score 2):

When your parent gets re-rendered, then your child component's `componentWillReceiveProps` function will be executed and unless you `return false` from `shouldComponentUpdate` of `Child`, it also will re-render. Now if you wan't to receive the updated value of `url` in the `Child` component you could probably implement the `componentWillReceiveProps` function of `Child` like

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(nextProps.url !== this.props.url) {
        //do something with the nextProps.url
    }

}
```

Comment: I should add - I would really hope not to change the code in the child component to force the change.  I'd rather use something in the parent to force a change.  Maybe just not possible with react.

Comment: as I said, you are not changing any behaviour in the child component. If your parent re-renders, your child will also unless you return false from shouldComponentUpdate and in your case you are changing the prop so in a normal case child will update. If there is some state in the child component that need to update based on the url prop, then you have to add the componentWillReceiveProps function in child and take actions there